# Call delegate function from another class

Tags: swift, xcode

I created a custom class with function delegation. Is it possible to call the didPlaneUpdate function in ViewController1 by calling the addToPlane () function from ViewController2 ? Below is my code:

```
// CustomClass.swift:

protocol PlaneDelegate: class {
    func didPlaneUpdate()

}

class Plane {
    static let shared = Plane()
    
    weak var delegate: PlaneDelegate?
    
     public init() { }

     public func addToPlane() {
         updatePlane()
     }

    public func updatePlane() {
        delegate?.didPlaneUpdate()
    
    } 
}
```

```
// ViewController1.swift:

class ViewControllerPlane: UIViewController, PlaneDelegate {
    var plane = Plane()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        plane.delegate = self
}

func didPlaneUpdate() {
        print("test updated")
}
```

```
// ViewController2.swift:

var plane = Plane()
plane.addToPlane()
```

or

```
// ViewController2.swift:
Plane.shared.addToPlane()
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Your issue is that when you do `Plane()`, it's creating a NEW instance of `Plane`. So `ViewController1` hsa its instance, and `ViewController2` its own instance. You see the issue? The delegate isn't set in case of VC2, because it's not set.

Comment: Yes, but when I call a delegate in VC2 I have to create a protocol and the function will be called in VC2 and I wanted it to be called in VC1 Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Are you initializing VC2 from VC1? if yes, then make one protocol in vc2 like "func updateVC1()" and implement in vc1 so that when you call VC2.delegate?.updateVC1(), you will get a call in VC1 from there you can call plane delegate.

Other simple but highly not recommended approach is , keep the reference of VC1 in VC2 if it's a one time task.